# GCP Command to Read All User's Permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Is there a way to list all permissions from a user in GCP?

I know there is this command:

> gcloud projects get-iam-policy "project-ID"

but I can only see the IAM roles I have set up in the IAM console. For example I do not see the IAM role

> BigQuery Data Viewer

that I have set up to a user on a dataset in the BigQuery page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in GCP is there a way to list all permissions of an user?

In Google Cloud Platform there is no single command that can do this. Permissions via roles are assigned to resources. Organizations, Folders, Projects, Databases, Storage Objects, KMS keys, etc can have IAM permissions assigned to them. You must scan (check IAM permissions for) every resource to determine the total set of permissions that an IAM member account has.

These features are both a strength and a weakness in Google Cloud authorization, security, and auditing. These features are very powerful when understood well.

Comment: Ok I understand we can only read roles and not permissions. But what you mean that I must scan a resource for IAM, what's the per-resource IAM command?

Comment: @toto' The command depends on the resource. Each resource that supports IAM has its own command set. For example, with Cloud Storage review the command `gsutil iam`. For Cloud KMS, `gcloud kms keys get-iam-policy`. There are commands for each supported resource type.

Comment: makes sense. Would you mind to suggest what is the one for BigQuery? I can't find a valid option for the bq command. tks

Comment: @toto' The command to view IAM permission in BigQuery is `bq show`. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

Comment: @toto' You might wonder why all the seperate commands. Years ago when most Google services where released, Google IAM did not exist. Permissions where controlled by the service. Today, Google is rapidly advancing authorization and security by integrating more universal systems and in some cases adding new types of identity and access control.

Comment: thanks! Yes too many commands make things not so simple. Btw: the output of "bq show" displays  -- "role": "READER",  "userByEmail": "xxxx@gmail.com" -- Ok but as per UI and doc shouldn't the role be named "Data Viewer" ? :)

Comment: @toto' - sometimes you have to translate from the service role name to IAM role names. `Data Viewer` is not a BigQuery role name - it is an IAM role name.

Comment: In principle, the Cloud Asset Inventory API could be used to export all IAM policies in one go instead of using all different product-specific commands - but then you have to parse / query the output afterwards.

Comment: The command is on Beta version, you can use this command line:  gcloud iam list-testable-permissions

Answer (score 6):

You can list the roles associated to a user or service account by tweaking the output of `gcloud projects get-iam-policy` with the flags '[--flatten](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--flatten)', '[--format](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--format)', and '[--filter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)':

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCP PROJECT>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="table(bindings.role)" \
--filter="bindings.members:<THE USER OR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"
```

The output is the following in my test scenario:

```
ROLE
roles/bigquery.dataViewer
roles/owner
```

Comment: I get an error: ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) Name expected [default *HERE* 'table(bindings.role)'].

Comment: @toto' That's odd. It works just fine on my end using the Cloud Shell. Anyway, try replacing the single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`) when specifying the value for `--format`, so that line looks like this: `--format="table(bindings.role)"`. Also make sure you're running the latest Cloud SDK with `gcloud components update`.

Comment: yes the problem was (") quotes. However this does not solve my problem since I can only get the project's level roles and not e.g. what I have set up on BigQuery.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to search for "foo@bar.com" within IAM policies under an organization:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:foo@bar.com" | egrep "resource:|role:|user:foo"
```

You can change scope to a project or a folder.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

It doesn't cover all the policies though: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types

More details can be found in another post: [How to list, find, or search iam policies across services (APIs), resource types, and projects in google cloud platform (GCP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480678/how-to-list-find-or-search-iam-policies-across-services-apis-resource-types)

Answer (score 3):

When we think about the permissions of a user, it would be wrong to think of there being some kind of master table that says "User X has all THESE permissions".  Rather, we need to re-orient our thinking to think along a different dimension.  Think of a *thing* that you want to protect (a resource) and then we can say "This resource (Z) allows user X to perform Y".

In GCP, we also don't assign permissions but roles which are collections of permissions.

Going back to your ask, this means that we can't list all the permissions for a user because a user doesn't "have" permissions, instead a user posses roles relative to a resource.

Imagine a file on your filesytem called "A" which user X can read but not write.  Now imagine a file on your filesystem called "B" which user X can write but not read.  We can't correctly say that user X has both "read" and "write" permissions.  While there are some files the user can read and some that the user can write it isn't true to say that the user can read and write all files.

And to reach a conclusion ... for any given set of resources you can ask that resource what users have what roles on that resource.

We have an API that can be used to determine if a user can perform a named operation against a given resource ... see: [Testing permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions).

Comment: ok thanks makes sense. But looks that does not scale well since it becomes quite complex to scan "all resources on per-user basis" to understand "who can access to what"..

Comment: @toto' ... Yuppers ... I also don't see a clean way to ask for all the resources that a user has some permission upon but flipping it around and asking for all the users who have a permission on a named resource becomes trivial.  Let us also not forget that groups can also be associated with resources and a specific user may or may not be a member of a group.  It might get even more complicated to learn what all a specific user can do.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this small script. It gives details like member id, roles it is assigned with and project Name

```
for list in `gcloud projects list | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'`; do gcloud projects get-iam-policy $list --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.members,bindings.role,$list)"; done;
```